# How to pre-populate WTForm FileField with current image file name?

Tags: flask, flask-wtforms, filefield

When a user wants to update a post using a WTForm, how I can I pre-populate the FileField input on the form so that it displays the current image name?
Currently, the user has to upload the same image every time that they update other aspects of the post otherwise the current image will be removed as the post is being updated without an image.

How I am currently pre-populating the form:

```py
    if request.method == 'GET':
        form.title.data = post.title
        form.language.data = post.language
        form.alt.data = post.alt
        form.text.data = post.content
        form.tag_1.data = post.tag_1
        form.tag_2.data = post.tag_2
        form.tag_3.data = post.tag_3
        form.image.data = post.img # This is the line where I am trying to pre-populate the FieldField
```

Answer (score 1):

*Currently, the user has to upload the same image every time that they update other aspects of the post otherwise the current image will be removed as the post is being updated without an image.*

I was stuck with the same issue while working on a project. Though I did not solve the issue of pre-populating the filefield, I had a work-around. I did the following.

1. While the request.method is 'GET', check whether the image attribute in the database is NULL. If it is not null, the location of the image file should be passed to the filefield. Using your variables, in your routes.py, it would be,

   ```
   form.image.process_data(path_to_image)
   ```

Display an image thumbnail under the filefield in the HTML form using Jinja2 if condition, to let the user know that an image is already there. (I was using a Bootstrap card)

```
    {% if form.image.data%}
    <div class="card" style="width: 12rem;">
    <img src="{{form.image.data}}" class="card-img-top" alt="{{form.alt.data}}">
    <div class="card-body">
    <p class="card-text">{{form.alt.data}}</p>
    </div>
    </div>
```

2. During POST, check whether the form.img data is NULL. If it is not NULL, write to the database. In your routes.py, it would be,

   ```
    if form.image.data.filename:
      post.img = form.image.data.filename
   ```